# How to configure DNS properly while two LANs are running?

Tags: dns

The device can't ping www.google.com but ping 8.8.8.8 is okay. My OS is Android 6.0.1, the kernel is 4.1.15

I've tried the resolv.conf and /etc/hosts. But these methods seem can not work on Android.

And I couldn't figure out what the exact problem is.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr EE:DE:17:79:BB:42
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ecde:17ff:fe79:bb42/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:600 TX bytes:1166

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:C6:81:79:01
          inet addr:192.168.120.57  Bcast:192.168.121.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:fe81:7901/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41709 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2738793 TX bytes:8354
```

I closed the netd service so that it is able to configure eth0 and eth1 respectively.

Here is my IP rule

```
0:      from all lookup local
9998:   from all to 192.168.120.0/23 lookup 4
9999:   from all to 192.168.1.0/24 lookup 3
10000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000/0xd0000 lookup legacy_system
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10063/0x1ffff lookup local_network
15000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_system
16000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_network
17000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup local_network
23000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff uidrange 0-0 lookup main
32000:  from all unreachable
```

Here is a result of ping IP, you can see the response is fine.

```
root# ping 192.168.120.1
PING 192.168.120.1 (192.168.120.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.120.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.120.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.986 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.120.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.00 ms

root# ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.718 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.420 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.403 ms
```

But ping google always returns unknown.

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

I expect I could ping IP and URL in my case.

BTW, the DNS from eth0 192.168.1.245 and the DNS from eth1 is 8.8.8.8

Comment: Why might anyone want to connect one Android device to two LANs at the same time?

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to explain my understanding of DNS on Android. It will help you troubleshoot related problems and serve me as future notes.

## DNS

Domain Name Resolver has traditionally been a part of OS's C library (commonly called libc). `GNU libc` (which is most common on Linux distros) implements a complicated name resolution mechanism named NSS which can prioritize in what order database services like LDAP / NIS, local `files` (`/etc/hosts`) and `DNS` have to be used in order to resolve host / domain names. DNS resolver then reads `/etc/resolv.conf` to get the name server address which is to be queried.

Unlike `GNU libc`, Android's `Bionic libc` (which [depends](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/libc/Android.bp#1568) on `netd` for DNS) doesn't regard `/etc/resolv.conf` unless [ANDROID_CHANGES](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/libc/dns/resolv/res_init.c#286) build variable is defined (only when libc++ is built as [static library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/libc/Android.bp#190)?). However [/etc/hosts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/libc/dns/net/getaddrinfo.c#67) entries are [valued](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/libc/dns/net/getaddrinfo.c#197) by Android's resolver when resolving names.
But if you are using a statically compiled / linked binary with some other - such as `musl` or `uC` or `diet` - libc, that must be reading `/etc/resolv.conf` to get Domain Name Server's IP address. [Busybox ping](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/busybox/blob/5d4827c9a980b058194da560caa1060476e25a8d/networking/nslookup.c#L668) is a common example.

## Android's DNS

Within Android's Java runtime environment, either a DHCP provided or manually set or [hard coded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/core/res/res/values/config.xml#1861) DNS server is used. Properties `net.dns1` and `net.dns2` are set with values of DNS servers received from [DHCP server](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpClient.java#153) (on Wi-Fi or Mobile Data) by `ConnectivityService` and then [forwarded](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4136850b80865141e554b61068c51f1d525b2600%5E%21/#F0) to `netd`. Starting with Android Oreo, these properties are [no longer available](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#o-pri) through Android APIs, but only [readable](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c02ac733d210e5769cd779100d671bc43fe0ec3b) as `root` or `shell` - once [removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e6cbb02e4c7d1a6d252d6aded3ade9b8a31d88a) then [re-added](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e3b85dfbc1dde8d229410f54c75c1efa4bb09fbe). So changing properties `net.dns*` using `setprop` only affects the programs (running with UID `0` or `2000`) that explicitly read these properties. One such example is [meefik's busybox](https://github.com/meefik/busybox/blob/a3a9e9b055a7607902f119d7de2130aae03336f6/contrib/patches-1.29.3/nslookup.patch#L454). Also there were some other [DNS related properties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dhcpcd/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r38/dhcpcd-hooks/20-dns.conf#11) set in good old days of `dhcpcd` which was the DHCP client up to Lollipop.

See some more details in [How does Android OS do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526).

#### Caching

DNS queries are cached on Android by `netd` as `NSCD` does on Linux distros to speed up name resolution. Android has a [commandline tool `ndc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/server/CommandListener.cpp) that could clear DNS cache but the command was [removed in Android 7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/767cd3fc050503a52bb03ce1ac72dc6ae2788666). Now it's possible to bypass caching by setting environment variable [`ANDROID_DNS_MODE`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/server/main.cpp#124) which prevents Bionic libc from proxying back to `netd` service for cache lookup. See [How to modify environment variables like PATH at startup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217894/218526) to set the variable globally.

#### How to set DNS

As mentioned earlier, previously different methods used to [change default Domain Name Servers](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/DNS#changing-default-dns) on Android don't seem to work now. Setting name servers and/or search domain name through commandline:

```
~$ ndc resolver setnetdns <network_id> <domain> <DNS>
```

<sup>* Commands syntax is a bit [different](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/DNS#resolver-commands) on older versions</sup>

Similarly `ndc tether dns set` works for `dnsmasq`. To get current network ID:

```
~$ dumpsys netd | grep 'Default network'
```

Clear set DNS servers:

```
~# ndc resolver clearnetdns <network_id>
```

However some apps may sometimes bypass Android's name resolution mechanism trying directly reach out to some nameserver, I have observed WhatsApp. Or the hard-coded value is used (may be when router is [advertising the IPv6 DNS server](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182470/218526)). The only certain working option is `iptables DNAT`:

```
~# iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 1.1.1.1:53
```

DNS servers can also be [configured in Settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205775/218526) for Wi-Fi network. Android 9+ supports [Private DNS](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/dns-over-tls-support-in-android-p.html) / DNS over TLS (DoT) which sends encrypted DNS queries on [port 853](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/server/ResolverController.cpp#77) as standardized in [RFC7858](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7858#section-3.1).

Non-root solution which works for both Wi-Fi and Mobile data is to use VPN apps like [Virtual Hosts](https://github.com/x-falcon/Virtual-Hosts/releases/) or [Personal DNS Filter](https://github.com/IngoZenz/personaldnsfilter) which intercept DNS traffic and makes queries to configured upstream DNS server.

#### Testing

To test what name server is being used by `connectivity` and `netd` services in Java runtime:

```
~# dumpsys connectivity | grep CONNECTED | grep -o 'DnsAddresses: \[[^ ]*'
~# dumpsys netd | grep -A2 'DNS servers:'
```

And those used by tethering forwarding DNS server:

```
~# ndc tether dns list
~# logcat -d -s TetherController,dnsmasq | grep -E 'update_dns|nameserver'
```

To see where the DNS queries are going, you may capture traffic destined for port 53:

```
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -j LOG --log-prefix 'DNS_QUERIES '
~# iptables -I OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -j LOG --log-prefix 'DNS_QUERIES '
~# dmesg -w | grep 'DNS_QUERIES'
```

Or

```
~# tcpdump -n -i any port 53
```

If the queries are not going to desired destination, there is some trouble with your DNS configuration, particularly if you use VPN. Please note that `iptables` and `tcpdump` (capturing on port `53`) won't work with Private DNS (port `853`). Dynamic nature of RPDB and routing tables ([rt_tables](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/server/RouteController.cpp#184) keeps on changing, [main](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r45/server/RouteController.cpp#700) table is not used) accompanied by fwmark ([SO_MARK](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-socket/)) make things complicated for manual control.

So if above mentioned steps don't work, there's nothing much you can do to fix DNS issues on Android devices. A Factory Reset or re-flashing of ROM may resolve the problem.

Additionally, if a local DNS server is provided by DHCP (server on Wi-Fi router), you may check if that's really listening on port 53:

```
~# nmap -e eth0 -sUT -p53 --script=dns-recursion 192.168.1.245
```

Comment: @IrfanLatif could you edit the answer and clarify the state of DNS leakage in case of `Private DNS` mode. Which system apps can bypass it (boot time or after boot) and can aforementioned apps with built-in dns services do that as well (What's App)?

Comment: "ndc resolver " no longer work since Android 10, how it should be done in newer Android Versions?