# incorrectly receiving DNS settings from AP when connecting to public wifi

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns, lan, dhcp

I had to fly recently. The flight had in-flight entertainment through gogoinflight, but I couldn't access it on my phone while everyone around me could.  I thought the problem was with the router but I couldn't access the public wifi in the destination airport, either.  I couldn't even open the wifi login pages to accept the user agreements. Nothing seemed to work!

Cellular internet works fine.  Wifi at home works fine.

On another recent flight, I also took my laptop so I could check network settings against my phone's settings.

```
# ip addr
```

yielded the same subnet and same gateway

```
# ip route
```

yielded the same routes, too.
(from memory)

```
# ip route
172.19.131.141/23 dev wlan0 proto kernel dhcp scope link src 172.19.131.0
```

from my laptop, the login page, or airborne.gogoinflight.com was in the 172.19.13**4**.x subnet, but that should be fine based on the route's mask (/23).

for good measure, I added a 0.0.0.0/0 route through wlan0 but still nothing.
At this point, it looked like my phone knew how to get at IP addresses, but there was a problem with the DNS settings.
I checked DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf on my laptop:

```
/etc/resolv.conf
--------------------
nameserver 172.19.(something).(something)  <--essentially, the access point transmitted the DNS to my laptop correctly and I was able to resolve addresses without problems
```

on my android phone:

```
/system/etc/resolv.conf
------------------------
nameserver 8.8.8.8 <--because google and android...
nameserver 8.8.4.4 <--because google and android...
nameserver 172.19.(something).(something)  <--essentially, the access point transmitted the same DNS server to my phone when I connected.
```

Even though I know it doesn't matter, I removed the WAN dns entries to google for good measure and made the resolv.conf file match my laptop's, but to no avail!
I tried multiple browsers (Chrome and Firefox), too,  to make sure it wasn't a browser setting.

any ideas?

Comment: Android's bionic libc resolver doesn't use `/etc/resolv.conf` normally: http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/bionic/libc/dns/resolv/res_init.c#286. And `ip route` isn't enough to see Android's routing table. It only shows main (254) table, while Android uses table 97 for WiFi.

Comment: Hi, Irfan.  Thanks for your response. I am unfamiliar with libc's dns resolver.  Glancing through the code, it looks like it's parsing a file called _PATH_RESCONF, which, as found in resolv_private.h, is defined as "/etc/resolv.conf" or "/etc/ppp/resolv.conf" (I don't know the value of ANDROID_CHANGES).  My phone doesn't have a "/etc/ppp/resolv.conf" file, so that leads me to believe it uses "/etc/resolv.conf".  This is contrary to what you suggested. What would it use if not /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526. Android's DNS resolver uses nameserver values received from DHCP which the client doesn't save to `/etc/resolv.conf` or any other file.