# How to know the address of the dns server I m using?

Tags: 9.0-pie, dns, 4g, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

Simple question but I couldn t find the answer anywhere. It is not part of ip informations and the information is not trivial when being connected to the Internet over lte.

`getprop | grep dns` is returning nothing.

Comment: Check in `dumpsys connectivity` or `dumpsys netd`. Se details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526

Comment: busybox nslookup www.google.com if you have it

Comment: @alecxs you re confusing with Windows. It doesn t tell about the current nameserver.