# Android 9: Configure DNS while connected via cable

Tags: dns

I've got an Android TV Box (orbsmart S86) running on Android 9. It is connected to the LAN and internet via a cable. Wifi is not used.

Now I've configured PIHole on another device and want to tell the android box to use the Pihole as DNS.

When using WiFi, I can go to the WiFi-settings and configure the settings there. How do I do this on this device?

So far I've tried `ndc resolver setifdns eth0 mydns` but without luck.

Note, that I've got root access.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su
setprop net.dns1 <dns here>
```

eg, setprop net.dns2 123.123.123.123

Comment: As of Android 8, "*The system properties `net.dns1`, `net.dns2`, `net.dns3`, and `net.dns4` are no longer available*" ([source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#o-pri)), but may work. More explanation here: [How to configure DNS properly while two LANs are running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)