# How to route all my Android phone own's DNS request to 8.8.8.8 in iptables with root?

Tags: dns, iptables

```
su
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 8.8.8.8:53
```

The above command is really working, but only for client phones who are using my phone's WiFi hotspot.

The result I need is for my phone itself. I want to route all my DNS queries only through 8.8.8.8 without using a VPN but with iptables.

Comment: Can you just set the DNS through the settings on your phone? A quick search of "android change dns to google" throws up loads of tutorials on how to do this

Comment: Yes I know dns setting in phone's setting. for some reason i do not use those feature . I want to do it via iptables

Comment: [How to configure DNS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526)